# Pattern recognition puzzle, ...$5$ , M , $6,5040,$ ... ; then M=?

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

> The following pattern puzzle problem was given to me by one of my friend:
>   $$\color{red}{5}$$
>   $$\color{blue}{24 \quad \quad \quad \text{M}}$$
>   $$\color{red}{4 \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 6}$$
>   $$\color{blue}{40320 \quad \quad \quad 5040}$$
>   $$\color{red}{8 \quad \quad \quad  3}$$
>   $$\color{blue}{6}$$
>   $\color{blue}{\text{M}}=?$

Comment: Hi welcome to Puzzling SE! Can you provide the link to the site where you got it from if you didn't make the puzzle yourself? ;)

Comment: @North actually one friend has given this problem to me in my whatsapp, so i don't know where he has got this problem; sorry for the inconvenience :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The numbers

> In blue look like they ought to be the factorials of the number in red directly counterclockwise to it, with the exception of the red 6 and the blue 5040 = 7! I’d imagine either the 6 should be a 7 or the 5040 should be 720.

That said,

> I’d hazard that the red 5 means the blue M should be 5! = 120.

Therefore

> M = 120.